# Sendmail issue: Cannot exec /etc/mail/smrsh: Permission denied

Tags: sendmail, dspam

When sending mail to an alias, I am getting the following error:

mail.err shows:

```
Jan 26 13:02:44 sm-mta[4816]: p0QD2fZW004812: SYSERR(root): Cannot exec /etc/mail/smrsh: Permission denied
Jan 26 13:02:44 sm-mta[4815]: p0QD2fZW004812: to="|/usr/bin/dspam --user global --class=spam --source=error", ctladdr=<spam@domain.com> (8/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=prog, pri=38439, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Operating system error
```

My /etc/mail/aliases shows:

```
spam:                   "|/usr/bin/dspam --user global --class=spam --source=error"
```

I am sure this is a permissions issue, but I don't really know where to begin looking.  I've tried various things, but nothing seems to solve the problem.  What other info can I look at to figure out what the problem is?

Unfortunately this is not one of those simple questions/problems so my question may be a bit vague.

Update with: ls -la /etc/mail/smrsh

```
total 8
drwxr-sr-x 2 root  root  4096 2011-01-24 14:14 .
drwxr-sr-x 9 smmta smmsp 4096 2011-01-26 14:54 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  mail    14 2011-01-24 14:14 dspam -> /usr/bin/dspam
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  mail    26 2011-01-19 19:54 mail.local -> /usr/lib/sm.bin/mail.local
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  mail    17 2011-01-19 19:54 procmail -> /usr/bin/procmail
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for a binary to be able to be executed by sendmail with `smrsh` activated you need to add a link in the smrsh directory (at least in RedHat)

So you should do the following

```
cd /etc/smrsh
ln -s /usr/bin/dspam dspam
```

And then change your aliases to

```
spam:                   "|dspam --user global --class=spam --source=error"
```

Otherwise you can always disable the smrsh functionality from sendmail, but I do not recommend that option

Comment: Incidentally, I moved from Redhat (and that's how I had it configured there).  Now on Ubuntu, I notice that smrsh is in /etc/mail/smrsh.  Within that folder I have: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root  mail     dspam -> /usr/bin/dspam.  Wondering if it's not a perm issue on the link or the folder.

Comment: Hm could be, check that the mail user can both get in that dir and execute that script without issues, I normally check with `su - mail -c "command goes here"`